# Meteor find an object in MongoDB by _id when it is a number

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I have a document inserted in a collection with `{ _id : 0, ... }` and I cannot find it using `collection.findOne({ _id : 0 })`, it returns undefined. Querying it from the mongo shell works fine however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `collection.find(0)` if the `_id` is 0, `collection.find(23123)` if the _id is 23123.